# LinearLayout issues to auto-size height (Kotlin / Android)

Tags: kotlin, android-linearlayout

I'm having issues getting the height of my linear layout to automatically increase to fit my content. As you can see in the screenshot below, the date text gets cut off. Any ideas on how to fix this, please? Thank you.

[image]

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/boxes_view_case_details"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/color_bar_case_details"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:weightSum="3">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/form_type_case_details"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="N-400"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1.2"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="Form"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/last_updated_date_case_details"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="Apr 13, 2021"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:layout_weight="1.2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="Last Updated"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/days_since_case_details"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="19"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1.2"
            />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="Days Since\nLast Update"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Why don't you use "wrap_content" ?

Comment: hmm, I thought 0dp was the same, but you're right, thanks!